# What does it mean by "the type of the class modeled by this Class object"?

Tags: java, literals, type-parameter

From the [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> T - the type of the class modeled by this Class object. For example, the type of String.class is `Class<String>`. Use `Class<?>` if the class being modeled is unknown.

What exact does "the type of the class modeled by this Class object" mean? Pardon, but this something look odd to me and I can't understand that much.

Comment: You write a class: `class Foo {}`. That defines the type`Foo`. At runtime, you can access the properties of this type Foo using the instance of the type `Class<Foo>`. If for example you call `newInstance()` on a Class<Foo>, you'll get an object ot type Foo. Whereas if you call it on a Class<Bar>, you'll get an object of type Bar.

Answer (score 3):

As you may know, classes represent (in other words, *model*) things. A `String` represents a bunch of characters, a `FileInputStream` represents a file input stream, a `LocalDateTime` represents a date and time without a timezone, etc.

If you can understand that, then you should be able to understand that there is a class that represents the concept of "classes", called `Class`. This class is generic. *Its single generic parameter is the class that it represents.* For example, `Class<String>`, represents the class `String`, `Class<LocalDateTime>` represents the class `LocalDateTime`. This is what the documentation meant.

Let's see a concrete example:

```
Class<String> clazz = String.class;
System.out.println(clazz.getName());
```

In the first line I have retrieved an instance of `Class<String>` (or a `Class<String>` object). Now the object inside the variable `clazz` represents the `String` class! How cool is that? We can print the name of the `String` class by calling `getName` on `clazz`, as you can see on the second line. You can do other cool things with `clazz` as well, such as seeing what interfaces it implements, what is its superclass, what method it has, etc. This is what I mean by "the `Class<String>` object represents the `String` class.

Answer (score 1):

`T` type parameter is generic parameter, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/. In case of `Class<T>` it's type of instance of the class. As you can see from javadoc this parameter is used in several methods:
`T newInstance()`, `T cast()`, `Constructor<T> constructor()`.
E.g. you may instantiate new instance of `T` type from `Class<T>` object:

```java
Class<String> cls = String.class;
String str = cls.newInstance();
```

or cast to this class:

```java
Object obj = "some string";
Class<String> cls = String.class;
String str = cls.cast(obj);
```